# Oracle SQl Dev, display id, firstname, surname and users number of files

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to write a query in oracle sql developer that will list
UNum, FirstName, Surname, and the number of files the users has, if the user has 0 it should be displayed as 0 next to their name.

```
(PK) = Primary Key
(FK) = Foreign Key
```

The database schema is as follows:

```
Building(buildingNum(PK), Description, instname, buildName, state, postcode)
User(UNum(PK), buildingNum(FK), Surname, FirstName, initials, title)
File(FileNum(PK), title)
UserAccount(FileNum(PK)(FK), UNum(PK)(FK))
Job(JobNum(PK), id, title)
Interest(JobNum(PK)(FK), UNum(PK)(FK), Description)
```

So far i have tried the following block of code:

```
Select User.UNum, User.FirstName, User.Surname, Count(UserAccount.FileNum)
from User, UserAccount
where User.UNum = UserAccount.UNum
group by User.UNum, User.FirstName, User.Surname;
```

I end up with the result being a long list of Users made up of UNum, FirstName and Surname followed by the number of files they have, however none of the results return with a 0. the list also seems to be extremely long for the size of the database. How do i find those who also have 0 files and is there anything else im doing wrong? expected result should be a much shorter list of users including those who don't have any files (There are 7 people in the database with 0 files) Thanks.

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and **easier to convert to outer join** if needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want a `left join`:

```
Select u.UNum, u.FirstName, u.Surname, 
       Count(ua.FileNum)
from User u left join
     UserAccount ua
     on u.UNum = ua.UNum
group by u.UNum, u.FirstName, u.Surname;
```

This also introduces table aliases, which makes it simpler to write and read the queries.

You can also write this using a correlated subquery:

```
select u.UNum, u.FirstName, u.Surname, 
       (select count(ua.FileNum)
        from UserAccount ua
        where u.UNum = ua.UNum
       )
from User u;
```

This version might have somewhat better performance.

Answer (score 0):

You want a left join. That keeps rows from the table left of the join operator even if no matching row is found in the table right to it.

```
SELECT user.unum,
       user.firstname,
       user.surname,
       count(useraccount.filenum)
       FROM user
            LEFT JOIN useraccount
                      ON useraccount.unum = user.unum
       GROUP BY user.unum,
                user.firstname,
                user.surname;
```